# Problem after renaming section

Tags: sections

I had a section called vision which i renamed to articles. I did so by going in to sections and clicking the section and then changing..

Handle, Entry URL Format and Entry Template. I also copied and renamed all the template files.

Now i can load up the main page as server/articles. But none of the entry pages will load and I get a 404 error.

When i look at the entries they are still there and now say the uri is: articles/article-name and the data is all there..

Did i miss something that needs to happen to rename a section?

Comment: It should work as you describe – have you double checked that you have the right path for the entry template? If you changed the path, did you also remember to change the actual file path and/or name of your template? You might want to check your log file(s) in ```/craft/storage/runtime/logs``` as well – might be a clue in there.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I think this is what happened. When i saved the entry change i did change the Enrty Template name. However, it seemed to have generated it back to articles/_entry.

Then i went in again and updated the name back to the real name i was using.